# How to extract list elements that follow extracted list element?

Tags: python, list

I have been able to convert a body of text into a list and extract elements that have keywords in my list. However I would like to print out a certain number of elements that would follow what has already been extracted.

Example:

```
list = text.split('\n')

ex = [s + '.' for s in list
 if 'Address'  in s]

print(ex)
```

Output: 
['From 8 June 2018 1201 A M Local Time At Named Address.', '8 June 2019 1201 A M Local Time At Named Address.']

**Desired Output:
['From 8 June 2018 1201 A M Local Time At Named Address.', 'Flat 12, 13 Preston Drive, Kingston', '8 June 2019 1201 A M Local Time At Named Address.']**

Comment: Not clear. Can you add sample text data. Desired output is related to that

Comment: I don't understand what is happening, because your code says: 'Only allow strings that already have `"Address"` in them.', whereas your Desired Output has a string that doesn't have `"Address"` in it.

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean that the code *should only* add a full-stop to those strings that contain `"Address"`?

```
lst = text.split('\n')

def finishAddress(value):
    return value + '.' if 'Address' in value else value

ex = [finishAddress(s) for s in lst]

print(ex)
```